# zero padding in fft

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let `h` be a 5x5 matrix, why does zero-padding using `fft2` as in

```
H = fft2(h,250,250);
```

not give the same result as using `padarray` manually, as in

```
H = fft2(padarray(H,[122 122]));
```

Is it because in my second example, the padded matrix is only 249 columns and rows? Should I add an extra column/row of zeros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how padding works with the Fourier transform. Here is an example of how to replicate manually what `fft2` does when you specify padding inputs:

```
>> a=rand(5); b=zeros(250); b(1:5,1:5)=a;
>> A=fft2(a,250,250); B=fft2(b);
>> max(abs(A(:)-B(:)))

ans =

     0
```

Comment: To give this a bit more explanation to this correct answer, you zero pad by creating a 2D array that's the desired size, then placing the original signal in the top left corner of the padded result.  That's how you pad for the 2D FFT.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng for such a nice explanation. It worked!!